# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ERROR_MESSAGE for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I know this issue has been asked quite a number of times but the reasons are always different for occurrence of this hence asking again.

I recently upgraded my jenkins from 2.270 to 2.278 version.

After the upgrade when I tried running one of the pipelines I got the following error and the pipeline failed.

****groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ERROR_MESSAGE for class: groovy.lang.Binding****

The code snipplet where it points to look like this.

```
   def <func2>(body) {

      <some code>
      stages {
          stage('Initialise') {
            steps {
                buildName "${JOB_NAME}#${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                script{
                    if (env.RELEASE == "1.0"){
                        env.ERROR_MESSAGE = "Please provide RELEASE"
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
           post {
                    unsuccessful {
                        notifySlack(
                            **message: "Deploy Initialise failed: ${ERROR_MESSAGE}",**
                            channel:"${slackDeployChannel}")
                            script{
                                env.DEPLOY = 'no'
                            }
                    }
            }
        }
```

and one more place the env.ERROR_MESSAGE is being called

```
def <func1>(arguments) {
  try{
       <SOME CODE>
       return 0
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
       env.ERROR_MESSAGE = e.getMessage()
       return 0
     }
    }
```

both func1 and func2 are separate functions being called separately.
Not sure if env.ERROR_MESSAGE is being initialised or not.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: `env.ERROR_MESSAGE` is within the scope of the conditional block, so it cannot be accessed outside of that scope. You may need to declare it at a higher scope.

Answer (score 1):

It's failing while groovy parsing `"Deploy Initialise failed: ${ERROR_MESSAGE}"` as the scope of initializing ENV variable is limited.

It could be something like this :

define a variable and get it to assign and used where ever you want.

```
def errorMessage
def <func2>(body) {

      <some code>
      stages {
          stage('Initialise') {
            steps {
                buildName "${JOB_NAME}#${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                script{
                    if (env.RELEASE == "1.0"){
                        errorMessage = "Please provide RELEASE"
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
           post {
                    unsuccessful {
                        notifySlack(
                            **message: "Deploy Initialise failed: ${errorMessage}",**
                            channel:"${slackDeployChannel}")
                            script{
                                env.DEPLOY = 'no'
                            }
                    }
            }
        }
    
def <func1>(arguments) {
  try{
       <SOME CODE>
       return 0
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
       errorMessage = e.getMessage()
       return 0
     }
    }
```